# When de-evacuation occurs, what provides energy?

Tags: vacuum

When a syringe piston is pulled from its initial position to spray position by blocking the nozzle with a finger, creating a vacuum inside the syringe, the piston will probably get pulled back to initial state. What makes it move back? Is it the vacuum inside or the air outside?

Answer (score 2):

The vacuum does not pull, it is an illusion, what happens is the molecules on the air outside hit the piston and produces a force inwards, and because on the inside there is very little gas (or none if there were a perfect vacuum) there is no force to stop the piston prom moving inwards.